# Two mouse cursors with one mouse on two monitors

Tags: windows, mouse

I have a silly request.

[Windows]
I would like to have my one mouse produce two cursors, one on each monitor, both moving at the same time in the same area of each monitor, with left click clicking in the left monitor and right click clicking in the right monitor.  For actual right-click functions maybe keyboard shortcut (ctrl+click).

Anyone else ever want this or know where to find something that will do this?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: good question.  I want to do this because moving back and forth between two monitors takes too long, and turning the sensitivity up makes accuracy too difficult.  I could be almost twice as efficient utilizing two cursors over one, being able to switch between tasks on both sides almost instantly.

Comment: I find the keyboard the best tool to switch tasks instantly.  <Alt+tab>  Why not use that?

Comment: Think of it like this, If i had two touch-screen monitors, I could use both hands to interact with both screens.  I don't have touch screen monitors though, so I want two cursors.

Comment: I literally mean that 0.2 seconds it takes to move from one monitor to the other has become unbearably slow to me.  I'd like it to take 0.1 seconds and little mouse movement to switch between monitors.

Comment: That would conflict with how windows user interface operates with extended screen.